# Stop Current Password Requirement for Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having an issue with the edit user section of my site. For some reason I keep getting the error "Current password can't be blank" when trying to edit a user. We use devise to manage users, but I can't seem to find code anywhere that would generate this error.

Here is the code for the form:

```
- semantic_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |form|
    = devise_error_messages!
    = form.semantic_errors
    = form.input :first
    = form.input :last
    = form.input :birth_year, as: :select, collection: User.birth_range.to_a.reverse
    %i= t('users.edit.cast_biometrics_hint')
    = form.input :gender, as: :select, collection: gender_options, include_blank: false
    = form.input :eye_color, as: :select, collection: eye_color_options, required: false
    = form.input :hair_color, as: :select, collection: hair_color_options, required: false
    = form.input :ethnicity, as: :select, collection: ethnicity_options, required: false
    %li.select.optional#user_height_input
      %label{for: 'user_height'} Height
      %select#user_height_ft{name: 'user[height_ft]'}
        = options_for_select 0..9, resource.height_ft
      %span ft &nbsp;
      %select#user_height_in{name: 'user[height_in]'}
        = options_for_select 0..11, resource.height_in
      %span in
    = form.buttons
```

Comment: Are you sure that the password is already set for the user? Does it help to try with a newly created user?

Answer (score 8):

There is more info in the devise wiki about this. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password

Comment: That's great, but I still don't understand how to allow editing of the password without requiring the current password.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a solution that worked without providing current_password!

This solution still checks for valid password and password_confirmation if password is present?

So I created an updated version of update_with_password in user.rb

```
def admin_update_with_password(params, *options)
  current_password = params.delete(:current_password)

  if params[:password].blank?
    params.delete(:password)
    params.delete(:password_confirmation) if params[:password_confirmation].blank?
  end

  result = unless update_attributes(params, *options)
    self.assign_attributes(params, *options)
    self.valid?
    self.errors.add(:current_password, current_password.blank? ? :blank : :invalid)
    false
  end

  clean_up_passwords
  result
end
```

and in my users_controller.rb

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  email_changed = @user.email != params[:user][:email]
  password_changed = !params[:user][:password].empty?

  successfully_updated = if email_changed or password_changed
    @user.admin_update_with_password(params[:user])
  else
    @user.update_without_password(params[:user])
  end

  if successfully_updated
    flash[:notice] = "User updated successfully"
    redirect_to redirect_path
  else
    render "edit"
  end
end
```